# What is the difference between include a layout or include a fragment in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments

I am looking my Eclipse IDE for Android and I am thinking that most times I can do same actions including a layout or including a fragment because both can be managed throught Java class. I don't understand very well fragments after I have read many posts... I think I can create a responsive layout without them, only including another layout in my main layout. So... 
Do you think are there any differences between include a layout or include a fragment in Android? 
Can you explain me if an option is better than the another one?

Comment: Fragments are reusable portions of UI, so you don't have to recreate complex layouts/views and can also work with complex layouts/views dynamically with greater ease. If you don't plan on reusing any of your UI or creating complex, dynamic UI's, there is no need to implement Fragments really. Imagine if you created an Activity with a layout, but then wanted to reuse a menu from that layout. You could place the menu from the layout in a fragment so that it could be used again by just placing the fragment in your activity instead of having to redo the whole layout or create duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

The important part of this is that `Fragments` have their own lifecycle. This means you can start, pause, resume, stop, etc. a `Fragment`. You can't do any of that with a layout. It's also wise to note that `Fragments` contain their own layouts.

Comment: Yes, you have reason a fragment has its own lifecycle. So... most times I could include another layout to build a responsive main layout. This is true?

Comment: If you are developing for multiple devices, you can use standard layouts or fragments. Responsive design is accomplished by making sure you have images in the right resources folder.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai could you give a small example of why would a portion of the UI (Fragment) need its own life cycle? I am having a hard time picturing why and when would I ever have only a certain portion of the UI stop/restart/destroy/etc.
I can see more use on its reusability feature, but I only see pitch black on the life-cycle one.

Comment: Yes, please, show an example why we need to use a Fragment because its lifecycle, instead including a layout.

Answer (score 0):

We can consider a fragment as a sub activity. It has its own life cycle as a normal activity, but the life cycle of parent activity would affect the fragment activity.

But a layout is just a design which can be reuse by 'include' it to an activity. It don't have its own life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Commenly I used include, Because its easy to use base level of developers also.Because that its including lay out syntax is 'simple' it doesn't have java part.

In fragmemt ,We can consider a fragment as a sub activity. It has its own life cycle as a normal activity, but the life cycle of parent activity would affect the fragment activity

Mainly commene difference is  haven't life cycle.But most developera used fragment for intentation , In fact include have all java function support, it  excluded lyfecycle function.

IF YOU HAVE REUSE A PAGE THAT CONDAIN INTENT 
then you can choos include and easy to handle